# Check if a built-in type exists in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, global-variables

I need to determine whether or not the environment my compiled code is running in defines the `Reflect` object, and the `Reflect.getMetadata` method. It is not known in advance where the compiled code will run. It could be a browser, nodeJS, or an arbitrary V8JS runtime environment.

I'm currently checking for properties of known global objects, but this stinks badly:

```
if (
    typeof ((window || global) as any).Reflect === "object" &&
    typeof ((window || global) as any).Reflect.getMetadata === "function"
) {
    // the Reflect.getMetadata method is defined
    // ...
}
```

Is there a more elegant and bulletproof way of checking for the presence of these objects? TypeScript throws an error if I'm just checking for the presence of `Reflect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Typical. Spend a considerable amount of time searching for a solution to a problem, end up asking for help on StackOverflow, then find a solution right before the question is posted. Anyways, I'll leave it here in case anyone else runs into this.*

---

In TypeScript it is possible to declare the presence of a presumably existing type using the `declare` keyword:

```
declare abstract class Reflect {
    public static getMetadata(metadataKey: any, target: Object, targetKey: string | symbol): any;
}
```

After which the compiler (and through it, IntelliSense) will gladly accept `Reflect` and `Reflect.getMetadata` as existing objects, after which it is possible to check their runtime types in a nice and clean fashion:

```
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.getMetadata === "function") {
    // the Reflect.getMetadata method is defined
    // ...
}
```